# Can't connect to MySQL server remotely

Tags: mysql, linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I've read a lot of answers for this question, but didn't found the resolve.
I have an mysql server on Azure (ex. 13.25.147.140).

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
# bind-address=127.0.0.1
init_connect= ^`^xSET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci ^`^y
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci

[client]
default-character-set = utf8
```

Then, I did `sudo service mysql restart`

Then, granted permission for root:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'57.26.24.157' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> SELECT user, host from user;
+------------------+--------------+
| user             | host         |
+------------------+--------------+
| root             | %            |
| root             | 57.26.24.157 |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost    |
| mysql.sys        | localhost    |
| paymon           | localhost    |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost    |
| root             | localhost    |
+------------------+--------------+
```

But when I tried to connect from my PC, I got this:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 13.25.147.140
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'57.26.24.157' (using password: YES)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Not really an Azure question because it seems that you have solid connectivity. Have you tried creating a normal user? You can reference my Linux on Azure guide for MariaDB at https://linux.azure.david.betz.space/_/mariadb to see how to do that. I think that's a good next step.

Answer (score 0):

By default, mysql disallow root login remotely, it is a security precaution.
If you want to use root to login remotely for some test, we can use this command to modify it:

```
[root@jasonvm etc]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.1.73 Source distribution
mysql> use mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select host, user from user where user="root";
+-----------+------+
| host      | user |
+-----------+------+
| %         | root |
| 127.0.0.1 | root |
| localhost | root |
+-----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'password' with grant option;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Another VM to use root to login mysql:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mysql -u root -p -h 40.71.33.231
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.1.73 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [(none)]>
```

Comment: I have that 'root@%' in my DB.

Comment: @VladMarkushin  please try this command, 1 use mysql 2grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'password' with grant option;

Comment: @VladMarkushin in my test, the select result same as you, but still can't use root login remotely, we should grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%'.

Comment: ok, I'll tell you in another way. I have 'root@%' in my database BECAUSE I already use "grant all privileges on . to 'root'@'%'" before.

Comment: @VladMarkushin before you grant all privileges, you should select "mysql" database, use command "use mysql;"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135243/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-vlad-markushin).